# Aggregate functions in 2 tables with dates in common

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have the following 2 tables

```
id   km    date
1    22.1  2012-04-15
2    52.1  2012-04-14
3    72.1  2012-03-15
4    54.1  2012-03-14
```

and

```
id   lt    date
1    16.4  2012-04-03
2    22.6  2012-04-29
3    45.9  2012-03-2
4    13.1  2012-03-31
```

From this tables I need to get a rate by month, I mean, the number of km divided by number of lt in a month. I know I can get the sum of km by month using aggregate functions in a query and in other query the sum of lt, something like this.

```
SELECT SUM(km) FROM kilometers GROUP BY MONTH(date)
SELECT SUM(lt) FROM gasoline GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

Then I could manually divide km/lt for each grouped month. So the question is, can I do that on a simple query? Do I have to change the structure of my database?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just join the table data together by the month/year.  You would just need to handle the situation where `lt` is 0 or null for a month.  Note that you will also want to group by YEAR so it handles multi-year data appropriately:

```
SELECT k.year, k.month, k.km / g.lt
FROM (SELECT YEAR(date) as year, MONTH(date) as month, SUM(km) as km
      FROM kilometers GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)) k
JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) as year, MONTH(date) as month, SUM(lt) as lt
      FROM gasoline GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)) g
  ON k.month = g.month AND k.year = g.year
```

Sample output:

```
YEAR  MONTH  K.KM / G.LT
----  -----  --------------
2012  3      2.138982929974
2012  4      1.90256407322
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2942/6

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Indeed what I needed with a super fast answer